# Using Inserted values in triggers

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am writing a trigger for one of my tables. What I want to do is, I want to update another table column with one of the inserted fields.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_TestTrigger]
ON [dbo].[TableA]
FOR INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    SET NoCount ON
    DECLARE @variable UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    SELECT @variable = TableB.colA1 FROM TableB WHERE (TableB.colB1 = INSERTED.colA1) 
    IF (@variable != INSERTED.colA2)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TableB SET colB4 = INSERTED.colA2 WHERE TableB.colB1 =INSERTED.colA1
    END 
END
```

But it gives an error when Creating this trigger to the database.
The error is:

```
 "INSERTED.colA1" could not be bound.
 "INSERTED.colA2" could not be bound.
```

normally INSERTED have the valuse that are just inserted. So, how should I have the values that I have inserted to the table "TableA". If inserted can not be used like this, What is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should treat inserted like any other table

```
SELECT @variable = TableB.colA1 
FROM TableB 
     inner join inserted ON TableB.colB1 = INSERTED.colA1
```

Be aware that `inserted` may contain more than one row, so this won't actually provide the results you want all of the time

Comment: So, Is there a better way of doing this. To get the just inserted values to the database. Because I have to update the other table. And in my update also I have to use Inserted. intellisence doesnot give any inserted fields there also. :(

Comment: With a single UPDATE query that joins to inserted and compares INSERTED.colA2 to TableB.colA1

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the INSERTED as a table.